# Using await versus Result

Tags: c#, async-await

Can someone please explain what is the difference between using `await` and the `Result` in the async pattern, and where would I use each?

```
public static async Task<string> GetVersion(int port, string method)
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:" + port);
  return client.GetStringAsync("/test").Result;           //<===============this versus
  return await client.GetStringAsync("/test").ConfigureAwait(false);//<=====this
}
```

Comment: The `await` keyword triggers the `async` functionality.  Without the `await`, It's just an ordinary synchronous method.  To find out exactly how it works, read [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: @Robert the marking of a method `async` has more overhead then it being run synchronously.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: No doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling the `Result` will block the current thread until the operation completes. The `await` returns to the caller and continues with the rest of the method when the async operation is completed.

Comment: `will block the current thread until the operation completes` - or, very often, will block the current thread [for good](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).